# Effect of green energy on petro dollar system

Tags: united-states, oil

US economy in part related to petrodollar system where all oil from Saudi to be traded in US dollars there by creating demand for dollars. What happens to this system and its impacts when world gradually switches to green energy with little dependence on oil there by US dollars?